# issue with dynamically loading of javascript code

Tags: jquery, adsense, google-ad-manager

I have an issue with dynamically loading of javascript code, I am saving google ads dfp following code in my database:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      GA_googleFillSlot("300x250");
</script>
```

But while displaying this code with `Ajax`, its not displaying corresponding banner ads instead it's throwing javascript error `"Error: GA_googleSetAdContentsBySlotForSync is not defined"`.
How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to me like a problem of configuration of tags. Have you looked at [Introduction to the Google Publisher Tag](http://support.google.com/dfp_sb/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1649768&topic=1651546&ctx=topic)
 page and setup the page correctly?